# Como fazer busca em uma VirtualStringTree no Delphi sem usar Edit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, treeview

Eu tenho uma `VirtualStringTree` com alguns itens e quero implementar nela um recurso similar ao que um `ComboBox` possui.

Funciona assim: ao pressionar determinada letra ele deverá selecionar o primeiro item da grid, conforme eu vou pressionando a mesma letra ele vai passando pelos demais itens que começam com ela. Porém se eu começo a digitar uma palavra ele deve selecionar o item correspondente ao que eu digitei.

*Ex: Se eu pressionar a letra `f` uma vez ele selecionará o primeiro item que começa com a letra `f`. Se eu a pressionar tês vezes deverá selecionar o terceiro item que começa com a letra `f`.*

*Mas se eu digitar rapidamente `for` ele deve selecionar o item que começar com `for`, por exemplo `fornecedor`*

O que consegui fazer até agora é que ele selecione o item caso eu pressione uma letra, mas ele não passa por todos os itens como eu preciso e nem funciona caso eu digite o trecho de uma palavra.

Segue o código que faz a busca:

```
procedure TfrmGrid.SearchForText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; 
Data: Pointer; var Abort: Boolean);
var
  NodeData: PPonteiro;
begin
  NodeData := PPonteiro(vtvGrid.GetNodeData(Node)^);
  // Interrompe a pesquisa caso encontre um nó com o texto correspondente
  Abort := AnsiStartsText(string(data), NodeData.ITEM);
  if vtvGrid.GetFirstSelected = Node then
   Abort := False;
end;
```

O que vai no `KeyPress` da `VirtualStringTree`:

```
procedure TfrmGrid.vtvGridKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  foundNode : PVirtualNode;
begin
  inherited;
  foundNode := vtvGrid.IterateSubtree(nil, SearchForText, Pointer(Key));

  if Assigned (foundNode) then
  begin
    vtvGrid.FocusedNode := foundNode;
    vtvGrid.Selected[foundNode] := True;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Por incrível que pareça o `VirtualStringTree` já possui este recurso. Basta habilitar a propriedade `IncrementalSearch`, neste caso deixei `isAll` que pesquisa por itens começados com determinada letra ou por trecho do nome do item.